# Method's parameters

Tags: java, android, methods, parameters, instance

I've just started learning Android Development + I am a beginner at this.

I don't actually get how/where, in the case below, a parameter of a method in instantiated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(**Bundle savedInstanceState**) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RadioGroup group1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.orientation);
    group1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(**RadioGroup group**, int checkedId) {
        switch (checkedId) {
          case R.id.radioButton2:
            group.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            break;
          case R.id.radioButton1:
            group.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            break;
        }
      }
    }); 
}
```

Thanks for Your help

Comment: Parameter instantiated? It is passed to the method when it is called.

Comment: Right sorry I asked in a wrong way. Where a new instance of a class RadioGroup is created f.ex in onCheckedChanged and how come we access its method setOrientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html) is an interface, and you are creating an [annonymouse inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) on your:

```
//Take a note at the key word new 
setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener{//overriden methods here});
```

That's how it gets instantiated in your code. Hope it helps.

**Update**

1. Reference to [observer pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)
2. Custom action listener [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/677591/Defining-Custom-Source-Event-Listener-in-Java)

Comment: I had already known that, but thanks for your reply anyway. I was more interested in a deeper stuff how system actually sees it and processes it.

Comment: Oh I see what your question was. If you're curious on how actionlistener works, you might wanna look into observer pattern. So basically with actionlistner you register observers (or listeners) on a component that get called when a specific event occurs. I updated the answer with reference to obesever pattern, and custom action listener example. Take a look.